# I can't pull data from database because of $(this).data(temsilci_mail)

Tags: javascript, jquery

'I can't pull data from database because of $(this).data(temsilci_mail). I want to use email address as id'

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            
                // Temsilci Listesi Modal
    
            $('.temsilcibilgi').click(function() {
                var userid = $(this).data('temsilci_mail');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax-modal/temsilci-listesi-modal.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        userid: userid
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.modal-body').html(response);
                        $('#temsilcilistesimodal').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `$('.temsilcibilgi')` selector return an array of button elements and you set up a ***temsilci_mail*** data to all of theses earlier. Because if you use `$(this).data('temsilci_mail')` you need to put the mail as a data before.

You can check if ***temsilci_mail*** data exist by logging button element like `console.log($(this))` or by looking at the inspector and check that ***data-temsilci_mail*** attribute exist in each button.

If your problem is not that ***userid*** is undefined, then please give more precise information about your problem.